# Cropping and/or editing an UV map with multiple objects without joining them

Tags: uv, objects

I have this
[image]

and I'd like to stretch the contents to fill the UV map. How could I do that? Is there a way of editing a whole UV map containing multiple objects?

Thanks for the responses

Comment: You can use UV warp modifier... but you'll need to set it up for all your objects... So, I am not sure it is simpler ? Move the "to" object to move. Scale it down to scale up the UVs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be using the addon MultiEdit. You can edit multiple objects at once without joining them.

Download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9h7bqe7aza4b16p/MultiEdit_05.zip?dl=0

Blenderartist Thread: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-version-5-Multiple-Objects-Editing

To install it you have to go to *File* -> *User Preferences* -> *Install from File*, then select the .zip and click *Install from File*. Then tick the checkbox to activate the addon. If you don't want to repeat this every time you start up Blender you can click *Save User Settings*.

[image: getting into the user preferences]
[image: the other steps]

After installing it you can select all the objects you want to edit and click *MultiEdit enter* in the tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>). Then you can scale up your UV map. When you're finished you can click on *MultiEdit exit* to go out of edit mode. But be careful not to go back to object mode by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or using the drop down menu at the bottom of the 3D View. This will join your objects. [image: scaling up the UV map of all objects]

Comment: Multiedit seems to break my modifiers :/ (mirror and array) - stuff appears elsewhere

Comment: I managed to use it but only when applied (I had to do it anyway) so thank you :) It seems to reset modifiers though